# Design pattern when search service fail

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-data, hystrix

I have a UserRepository to search database (solr, elasticsearch, others...) and i have this user data in my SQL database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, others...), My question is what place do I put this? In repository ?  Or other abstraction (Service, Controller)?

My example is in Java, but i will apply this to java (Spring) and PHP:

```
public interface UserRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<User, String> {}
```

Comment: *what* is your question? please edit your answer so everyone gets your point

Comment: @Lino what place do I put this? In repository? Create a service just for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you you're doing things right

The [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) lets you abstract **where** the data comes from. So you use cases/controllers/whatever doesn't need to care about that

**BUT** the repository doesn't need to know the details about how to retrieve that data. That is a task for a [DAO (Data Access Object)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html). A DAO encapsulates the details about how the data is stored

So you repository can have several DAOs that access several data sources and coordinates them. e.g.

1. Use `myDAO1` to retrieve user data
2. if there is no user data in the data source `myDAO1` is fetching then use `myDAO2` to fetch another data source
3. Keep going until the repository find the needed data (maybe implementing a [Chain of responsability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)) or return null or throw an exception or do whatever you define to do

Comment: understand... I can create a UserRepository and he call DAO's (UserSQL and UserSolr for example) and my services, controllers call just repository, this a workflow ?

Comment: Can I do this with hystrix ? (if you know hystrix from Netflix)

Comment: 1. Check any blog post about Clean Architecture. It should clarify your mind about the workflow. 2. I haven't used Hystrix but I'd say that you can do it in any situation

Comment: Thanks :D , I will follow your words